# Creating a Database to a messenger application

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I need a Database in MySql that I can save Users and those users could have friends and send messages each other. I have a table Users that I can save the information user, but I don't know how I can save the friends, for example: the user 1 is friend of user 4, 8, 9 and the user 8 is friend of 5, 6, 10, 11. I thought creating a table Friends and save all friends but I think this table would be very big if I have many users. What is the best way to create this Database saving Users and their friends and messages to their friends? I know basic of table relationship.

Comment: You need a table giving each user a has and belongs to many relationship to the other users.

Comment: You can create a table RelationShip that contains (relationShipId, relationShipUser, relationShipFriend) where the relationShipUser is the fk to the user id, and relationShipFriend is also a fk to the user id, when you want to add a relation ship simply add a record in the table RelationShip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, create a table `users_rel` (or something) that has the fields `user_id` and `frienduser_id` and add the friends accordingly.

```
user_id | frienduser_id
1       | 4
1       | 8
1       | 9
8       | 5
8       | 6
...
```

Use user_id, frienduser_id as key to avoid duplicate entries.

Comment: but if I have 100000 users and each user can have 100 friends. wouldn't this table be very big? will queries return fast the results of a consult with many friends?

Comment: Use index on both frienduser_id and user_id, even if you have a huge number of records, the query won't exceed 0.5 sec.

Comment: Modeling this table, how would be the relationship to my table users? Many-to-many?